# ORA-01001: invalid cursor On SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, cursor

I have a package with 2 procedures - each have sys_refcursor as out parameter,
The first procedure works perfect,
The second has a different query and one gives me ORA-01001: invalid cursor.
I checked the query in sqlplus and it returns values.
What Can be the problem ?

I will put some of the code - but it's a long query so I can't put all.

```
 PROCEDURE bybranch (
        inputbranch    IN    CHAR,
        customerid     IN    CHAR,
        deftype        IN    CHAR,
        districtflag   CHAR,
        br_out_rec      OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS
    BEGIN
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mm-yyyy''';
        
        OPEN br_out_rec FOR 
        SELECT  to_date(TO_DATE('01-01-1988 00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') + numtodsinterval(w.curdate, 'minute'), 'dd-mm-yyyy' ) AS qdate,
        TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate)                                    + h.stime / 24 / 60, 'hh24:mi')                        AS stime,
        TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate)                                    +(h.stime +(
                CASE
......

                macdent$mac_nearbranch.branch = to_number(inputbranch)
        )
ORDER BY qdate,        stime;

        apex_json.open_object;
        apex_json.write('bybranch', br_out_rec);
        apex_json.close_object;
        CLOSE br_out_rec;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            htp.print(sqlerrm);
            
    END bybranch;
```

Comment: Please post the entire query and PL/SQL code as [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: OK - Thats the minimal examplae 

PROCEDURE bybranch (
        br_out_rec      OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS
    BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mm-yyyy''';
            OPEN br_out_rec FOR 
            SELECT * FROM DUAL;        
         CLOSE br_out_rec;
     END bybranch;

variable br_out_rec refcursor;
DECLARE
BEGIN
TABULA.GetTorim.bybranch(:br_out_rec); 
END;
/
print br_out_rec|


SQL>
ERROR:
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed


SP2-0625: Error printing variable "br_out_rec"

Comment: Also clarify when the error is raised. Your parameter is `br_out_rec OUT` but then you consume that cursor in the `apex_json.write()` call, and then close it. So the *caller* will see a closed cursor; and even if you didn't close it, it would be empty.

Comment: @liorke It's not *reproducible* code: you need to provide table definitions and other required objects for someone will be able to replay your setup. That's why it is named as *minimal*

Comment: Don't put blocks of code in comments - [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76216535/edit) and put it there as formatted text. It's also helpful if the code can be run in a fiddle - [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/2qRzhuc5) - that shows the same error you're getting, i.e. ORA-01001 not ORA-24338. And yes, the error is because of the `CLOSE`; what are you expecting the caller to be able to do with a closed cursor?

Comment: Ok, I opened a new question - before I saw your comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217980/sp2-0625-error-printing-variable-sys-refcursor

Comment: Why didn't you fix this one?