# SP2-0625: Error printing variable SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle

```
This is a minimal example:
```

I suspect there is some issue with the cursor itself , because it all started when I got ORA-01001  Invalid Cursor

```
create or replace
package TABULA.gettorim as 
PROCEDURE liorByBranch ( br_out_rec        OUT sys_refcursor );
end gettorim;
/
Package created.
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tabula.gettorim AS
    PROCEDURE liorbybranch (
        br_out_rec      OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) IS
    BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mm-yyyy''';
            OPEN br_out_rec FOR 
            SELECT * FROM DUAL;        
         CLOSE br_out_rec;
     END liorbybranch;
END gettorim;
/

Package body created.
SQL>

variable br_out_rec refcursor;
DECLARE
BEGIN
TABULA.gettorim.liorbybranch(:br_out_rec);
END;
/
print br_out_recSQL>   2    3    4    5
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
ERROR:
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed

SP2-0625: Error printing variable "br_out_rec"
```

I suspect there is some issue with the cursor itself , because it all started when I got ORA-01001  Invalid Cursor

Comment: You were told what the problem was [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76216535/266304). You haven't said why you have the OUT parameter or what you expect the caller to do with the cursor. They can't do anything with it after you've closed it; and in your fuller version you seem to be consuming it before closing as well, so there is no data available to the caller. So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm sending it out later on as apex_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you **closed** the cursor; don't do that.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE liorbybranch (br_out_rec OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mm-yyyy''';
  5
  6     OPEN br_out_rec FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL;
  7
  8     -- CLOSE br_out_rec;           --> here
  9  END liorbybranch;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var br_out_rec refcursor;
SQL> exec liorbybranch(:br_out_rec);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print br_out_rec

D
-
X

SQL>
```